# Fetch website that is relative to current directory

Tags: javascript, fetch

First of all, my directory looks like this (simplified):

```
website/
  index.html
  files/
    script.js
  api/
    site.html
```

`index.html` is using `script.js`.
In `script.js` I want to fetch `site.html`

`script.js`:

```js
fetch('./api/site.html')
.then(response => {
    response.json()
    .then(
        // code
    );
})
```

And instead of fetching `example.com/website/api/site.html` it fetches `example.com/api/site.html`

What should I change in fetch without specifying name of parent directory?

Comment: change fetch('./api/site.html') to fetch('api/site.html')

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but shouldn't that be "../api/site.html" ?

Comment: Okay, my hosting had a massive lag, it worked  Grumpy!